# How to render HTML file in Vue JS which is sent by the server?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, fetch

I am very new to Vue JS. Currently, I'm finding a way to render an HTML page that is sent by the server. Lest's assume I have a node router "health" that sends an HTML file as follows.

```
res.sendFile('test.html', { root: path.dirname(require.main.filename) + '/public/' });
```

In that case, can I try to access that file and render it this way by Vue JS?

```
<div id="app">
<div v-html="reactPage"></div>
</div>
<script>
let sessionId = "";
(function() {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            reactPage: undefined
        },
        created() {
            fetch('launch/health')
                .then(response => {
                    this.reactPage = response;
                })
        }
    })
})();
```

This code is not working as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only thing wrong here is the `fetch` syntax.  Try this:

```js
fetch('launch/health')
.then(response => {
  return response.text();
})
.then(data => {
  this.reactPage = data;
})
```

You could consider using `axios` for easier http requests.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Missing part is text(). You should use then() instead of than() since I'm using fetch API. But I have another question. I loaded a static HTML page successfully. But once I try to load an HTML page which initializes a react application I can not see anything. Basically I tried to load the react app inside the above Vue JS app. Do you think these two libraries (Vue and React) conflicting each other or something like that happening??. I used jquery  html() before replacing the dom with react app. Then it worked.

Comment: Glad it's working.  I did use `.then()`, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.  The syntax in the answer showed you the proper way to use `fetch`, and now the problem is fixed.  To your other question, it won't work.  You can't expect to load a compiled React application inside `v-html` unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any way to compile and bind the react page using Vue JS ??

Comment: No, Vue can't compile React apps.  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Since I'm using parcel as the build tool for the react app I think there should be a way to achieve this.

Comment: I combine the same react app to the DOM using JQUERY .html() successfully. So I don't think jquery also doesn't have a way to compile React. So I think this issue is not regarding compilation.

Comment: As I said, you can insert the HTML, and in fact that's what this answer was first regarding.  But you can't compile a React template using Vue's compiler.  If you just want to insert pre-compiled HTML, using Vue as a glorified HTML loader, and then sideload a React app to piggyback off of that, perhaps that's doable.  I can't say for sure.

Comment: I found a way to do that. You can use
  component(:is='reactPage && {template:reactPage}') instead of div(v-html='reactPage'). Thaks